# How can i install npm moduls on atom?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to install the bcrypt package and im using the "npm install bcrypt --python=python2" and i can this after i run it:
bcrypt@5.0.0 install C:\Users\User\node_modules\bcrypt

> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

```
node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
[bcrypt] Success: "C:\Users\User\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\napi-v3\bcrypt_lib.node" is installed via remote
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\User\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\User\package.json'
npm WARN User No description
npm WARN User No repository field.
npm WARN User No README data
npm WARN User No license field.

+ bcrypt@5.0.0
updated 1 package and audited 130 packages in 2.951s

1 package is looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I don't get any module in atom.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error that tells you that current folder you are working in does not have a node project set up, its missing the necessary package.json file (every node project has one and needs one).

There are 2 types of "install" with npm, first is global that that you mark with -g flag (`npm install bcrypt -g`), this will install whatever package into global node modules that can be executed from the node command line, the second one is installing / adding it to your project.

In order to add anything to your project you need to create your project, create a folder for your project, open cmd line and navigate to the folder, and run `npm init`, this will create a package.json file (after you answer few questions), then `npm install whatever` will add the package automatically to the package.json file. (there is also a `--save-dev` flag that adds node module to dev dependencies)